# Symfony2, How to make a form label class/attr different than its input?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I would like to build a form with label and inputs, but the class of them should be different. Code below creates the label for the input with same attr:

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
                ->add('hours', null ,
                  array('attr'=> 
                             array(
                                 'placeholder'=>'Working Hours',
                                 'class'=>'ui-spinner-box') ) )
    }
```

In my code above the `ui-spinner-box` will be outputted for both label and input. It will even put placeholder for its label.

So how to make it create `attr` for label separately so I can output something like below :

```
<label class="MYCLASSFOR_LABEL"   for="input_id">Hours</label>
<input class="MYCLASSFOR_INPUTS"  type="text" id="input_id" name="" value="" >
```

Answer (score 97, accepted):

As mentioned in the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#reference-form-twig-variables):

- attr      : A key-value array that will be rendered as HTML attributes on the field
- label_attr: A key-value array that will be rendered as HTML attributes on the label

You can set those attributes in twig template or in form builder:

**Twig template:**

- for symfony 2.1 and newer use:

  ```
  {{ form_label(form.hours, null, {'label_attr': {'class': 'foo'}}) }}
  ```
- in the legacy symfony 2.0 it used to be

  ```
  {{ form_label(form.hours, { 'label_attr': {'class': 'MYCLASSFOR_LABEL'} }) }}
  {{ form_widget(form.hours, { 'attr': {'class': 'MYCLASSFOR_INPUTS'} }) }}
  ```

**Form builder**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('hours', null, array(
        'label_attr' => array('class' => 'MYCLASSFOR_LABEL'),
        'attr'       => array('class' => 'MYCLASSFOR_INPUTS'),
    ));
}
```

Comment: Actually it has to be: `{{ form_label(hours, null, { 'attr': {'class': 'MYCLASSFOR_LABEL'} }) }}` because the second parameter is the label name. If you pass null it will still use the value set in build form

Comment: Possible, and much easier, in buildForm -- see my answer

Comment: small update to @insertusernamehere comment, it should be `{{ form_label(hours, null, { 'label_attr': { 'class': 'MYCLASSFOR_LABEL' }}) }}`

Comment: could not find this anywhere in the documentation but right on!

Answer (score 49):

This may be new, but there's an easy way to do this now:

```
$builder
    ->add('hours', null , array(
        'attr'=> 
            array(
                'placeholder'=>'Working Hours',
                'class'=>'MYCLASSFOR_INPUTS') 
        ) ,
        'label_attr' => array(
            'class' => 'MYCLASSFOR_LABEL'
        )
    );
```

The option you're looking for is `label_attr`.

Comment: How does this work for radio buttons (choice type)?  The label_attr only seems to apply to the overall label and not on the labels next to each radio button choice.

Answer (score 7):

This works for me in Symfony 2.3:

```
{{ form_row(form.hours,  {   'label': 'Hours:'
                            ,'label_attr': {'class': 'MYCLASSFOR_LABEL'}
                            ,'attr': {'class': 'MYCLASSFOR_INPUTS'} 
                        }
           )
}}
```

Answer (score 6):

The above is no longer correct, at least in the context I was using it. In Symfony 2.1 the solution is:

```
{{ form_label(form.item, label|default(null), { 'label_attr': { 'class': 'MYCLASS' } }) }}
```