# Can I use two different form_label tags?

Tags: symfony

I am using a [separate template](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#method-2-inside-a-separate-template) to define the blocks in my form.

I'd like to also customize a `form_label` within the same template as my form ([method 1](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#method-1-inside-the-same-template-as-the-form) here). This is because I've defined my `form_label` block for the purpose of rendering my actual input fields, but for `ArrayCollections`, I'd like to render things differently.

For example, I want to render an `emails` array. Here's my code:

```
<h4>{{ form_label(form.emails) }}</h4>
{% for email in form.emails %}
  {{ form_row(email) }}
{% endfor %}
```

For the `form.emails` label, I just want it to output the text (in this case, "Emails"), while for the actual `input` fields, I want to use what I've defined in my template (a `label` tag with class `control-label`, etc.). So, it's working as I desire for each `email`, just not for the `form_label(form.emails)` part.

Is this possible? Since I've already used

```
{% form_theme form 'TechrescueAdminBundle:Form:fields.html.twig' %}
```

I can't also use

```
{% form_theme form _self %}
```

Is there another way? If not, what's a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just set the class on the fly rather than using a new block?

```
{{ form_label(form.item, null, {'label_attr' : {'class': 'control-label'}}) }}
```

From : [Symfony2, How to make a form label class/attr different than its input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919619/symfony2-how-to-make-a-form-label-class-attr-different-than-its-input)

Comment: I'd prefer the label of the array to not be in a `label` tag at all. Also, this would mean I'd have to render each form element individually (label, widget and errors) instead of being able to use `form_row`.